# Add extra field to the formset while saving the formset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to know the alternate method to save data to the database that are not coming from the html form.

This is my models.py:

```
class product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("user")
    product = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    cost = models.IntegerField()
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class productform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = product
        fields = ["product","cost"]
```

This is my views.py

```
for formset in product_formset:

          cost = formset.cleaned_data['cost']
          product = formset.cleaned_data['product']

          product(
                    product = product,
                    cost = cost,
                    user = request.user,# here user is not coming 
                    ).save()              through the form.
```

Instead of using formset.save() here i am iterating through the formset to save the additional field "user". My question, Is there an easy way to save the additional field "user" without iterating. 
Somebody please correct the question if it is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it without iterating but you can simplify the code to this:

```
for product in product_formset.save(commit=False):
    product.user = request.user
    product.save()
```

Comment: again you are helping, i have only thanks to give..:-)